# Why I am I stuck at the "yes" bar when trying to update firmware on my Nikon D700?

Tags: firmware

I have a Nikon D-700 I downloaded the firmware version 1.04/1.03 to a formatted card with the .bin file but when I go to the menu to update, I have the yes button and I can see the previous and newer firmware versions but the menu will not allow me to select it. I am stuck in the yes bar and it will not go any further. Is the camera damaged or is there another way to update this?

Comment: Here are some good instructions:

Comment: Sorry about that...   https://photographylife.com/nikon-firmware-update  and https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/fw/15.html

Comment: Just wondered if you actually formatted the card on the camera first and not via a computer.Card needs format via camera only.Then add the bin file.

Comment: I formatted by camera then copied the .bin file and I tried formatting on the computer (FAT32) and neither method worked.

Comment: The right hand side selector does work for other menu options, just not in the firmware upgrade options

Answer (score 2):

You should not be pressing the selector button.  It's asking you to press the OK button, and that is at the bottom left.

[image]

Comment: You have solved my mystery and uncovered what a knucklehead I am.

Comment: Formatting cards works the same way, you can click the select until the last step, then you have to click OK.  Prevents you from mindlessly clicking and reformatting a card.

Answer (score 1):

[image]That's correct. It's showing you the current and new firmware.

[!Here is what my screen looks like. When I depress the select button, nothing happens. I can't select the version, It is stuck at yes and won't go any further.

There is no selection other than **YES**, do the upgrade.